# The sum of the lengths of the legs of a right-angled triangle is $12$, and the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{74}$. Find the total area of the triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

I am new to math and I feel stupid; I am trying to fix an issue and I would love it if some one could give me a hand and explain to me step by step. The main thing is I want to understand the solution; I don't just wanna a final number for each case.

Thanks in advance :)

> The sum of the lengths of the legs of right-angled triangle is $12$, and the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{74}$. Find the total area of the triangle.

[problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GOB4.png)

[image]

[image: problem 2]

> Find the minimum value of the function $y=2+x^2(3-x)$ in the intercept $[1;4]$.

[image: problem 3]

> Solve the inequality $\log_3(4x^2+1) \ge \log_3(3x^2-4x+1)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Since you are new here, let me tell you some of the rules and customs of the site.

Please ask one question at a time.

Please type your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting images.  Images are not searchable and not accessible to people using screen readers for example.

You will got a lot more help and a fewer votes to close if you show that you have made some effort.  What have you done on the problems?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please also write with appropriate punctuation and capitalization. itstoohardformetoreadyourquestionasitiswritten.

Comment: $$ \frac{1}{2}ab = \frac{1}{4}\left[(a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2)\right].$$

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). To help you get started, I have [typed formulas from the pictures](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2726900/revisions) in your post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint for Problem 8: we have $$a+b=12$$ squaring this equation we get $$a^2+b^2+2ab=144$$ Now use that $$S=\frac{ab}{2}$$ and $$c^2=a^2+b^2=74$$
Hint: $$y=2+3x^2-x^3$$ then $$y'(x)=6x-3x^2=3x(2-x)$$ and compute the values for $x=0,x=2,x=1$ and $x=4$

Comment: Once you get $a^2+b^2+2ab=144$ and $a^2+b^2=74,$ it's not so many more steps to find $\frac12ab.$

Comment: thank you ! this step a2+b2+2ab=144 was the breaker

Comment: That is nice, have a nice evening!

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem: you know that the area of a triangle is:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\cdot base \cdot height$$
So you need to find this values. By Pythagoras theorem you know that:
$a^2 + b^2 = 74$, and it is given that $a+b = 12$. Therefore: $a=12-b$, which can be substituted to obtain:
$$(12-b)^2 +b^2= 74$$
$$b^2 - 24b+144 +b^2 = 74$$
$$2b^2 -24b + 70 = 0$$
$$b^2 -12b+35 = 0$$
$$(b-7)(b-5) = 0$$
Hence $b=5$ or $b=7$, and therefore: $a=5$ or $a=7$
So the Area of the triangle when $a=$base and $b=$ height is?

Can  you continue from here?

Comment: yes i can :) thank you

Answer (score -1):

Hints for problem $8$. For the rest you *will have* to show some effort and self work:

If the triangle's legs are denoted $\;x,\,y\;$ , then we have that 
$$\begin{cases}\;x^2+y^2=74\\{}\\x+y=12\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies x^2+(12-x)^2=74\;$$

Solve the last quadratic in $\;x\;$ and find the numerical value of $\;x\;$ , and then of $\;y\;$ .

Comment: awesome ! i got the idea now , thanks buddy :)

Answer (score -1):

$x+y=12$;

$(x+y)^2= x^2+y^2 +2xy= 144$.

Pythagoras:

$x^2+y^2= (\sqrt{74})^2= 74;$

Hence : $2xy = 70;$

Area= $(1/2)xy= 70/4$. (Why)